# JavaScript Pig Latin vowel logic error, requesting code feedback

Tags: javascript, function, slice, charat

I'm working on the Pig Latin exercise and I don't understand what's wrong with my vowel logic that's making it console.log undefined?

```
function pigLatin(str){
    const vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    if(str.charAt(0) == vowel) {
        return str + "way";
    }
}
```

However, if I were to test words that don't start with a vowel, my code runs fine.

```
function pigLatin(str){
        const vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
        if(str.charAt(0) !== vowel) {
        var firstChar = str.slice(0, 1);
        return str.slice(1) + firstChar + "ay";
        } 
    }
```

Why is the first block of code setup incorrect? What am I overlooking or misunderstanding? Thank you.

Comment: You are comparing a string to an array

Comment: You need to iterate through the array and check each item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Yaakov Ainspan and Ramya Ramanthan for the clarification and for catching my mistake in the second block!

Here's what I came up with after much researching and experimenting.

```
function pigLatin(str){
    const vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    const consonant = "/[^aeiou]{2,}/"
    if(vowel.indexOf(str.charAt(0)) >= 0) {
        return str + "way";
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            if(consonant.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0){
                var firstChar = str.slice(0, i);
                var multiCon = str.slice(i, str.length);
                return multiCon + firstChar + "ay";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first I was running into the same problem with the second block in the `consonant` variable in the `if` string. Turns out I was making the same mistake-- checking a str to an array. The problem disappeared after I wrapped the `const consonant` in a string instead of the array square brackets.

Please do let me know if there are still problems with my code that I'm not foreseeing.  :)

Note: I'm aware of the other pig latin rule concerning words that start with a consonant but sound like a vowel (eg. "honest" in my code would be onesthay rather than honestway). I'm ignoring that rule.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you're using in `if` block is wrong -- you're checking if the first character of `str` is equal to `vowel` array itself. This will always be `false`.

Plus the condition used in your second example is simply the negation of the one in first, it will always evaluate to `true`. `if` block will run for strings beginning with vowels also.

```js
function pigLatin(str){
        const vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
        if(str.charAt(0) !== vowel) {
        var firstChar = str.slice(0, 1);
        return str.slice(1) + firstChar + "ay";
        } 
    }
    
console.log(pigLatin('arnor'))
```

Change your code to something like below, to **check if the first character of `str` is a member of `vowels` array**:

```js
function pigLatin(str){
    const vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    if(vowel.indexOf(str.charAt(0)) >= 0) {
        return str + "way";
    }
}

console.log(pigLatin('arnor'));
console.log(pigLatin('beorn'));
```